# Does this pointwise convergence hold?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise , does this mean $f_n^p$ converges to $f^p$?

Comment: Yes, of course. ($p>0$, and $f_n,f$ are nonnegative, right?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because $y\mapsto y^p$ is a continuous function.  If $g$ is continuous and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} g(f_n(x)) = g(f(x))$.